# How to map long REST urls in struts2 - using struts2 rest plugin

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, struts2, friendly-url

I've been learning to use struts2 rest plugin from a past few days. But no-where I found how to map long rest URLs.

For e.g.
If I want to map an URL like below :

```
/profiles/user-test/orders/64/item/4
```

where

```
username is user-test
order id is 64
item id is 4
```

How can I map something like this to a struts2 action ?

All I found on internet is just a single level being edited/displayed etc. But if I want to display something on multiple-level - then how to proceed ? Please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`Advanced Wildcard Mappings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097360/1654265), without the REST plugin:

> `/profiles/user-test/orders/64/item/4`
>
> username is user-test
>
> order id is 64
>
> item id is 4

The action configuration needed for this example would be:

```xml
<action name="/profiles/{username}/orders/{order}/item/{item}" class="fooBarAction">
    <result>fooBar.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: it worked!!.. sorry for the late reply, I was having university exams.

Comment: Although it doesn't work straight forward, I had to use regex to prevent username to span complete url after profiles/ and similarly, I used regex with other {named} variables.

Comment: Then answer your own question if you want, to help future visitors :)

Comment: So the Struts2 REST plugin is only useful with single level URLs? :( . Thanks for this answer, I'll try it out also.

Comment: This kind of mapping doesn't work while using with REST API. I mean, if there're actions/controllers say, `movies` `actors` `reviews` and to check the `actors` or `reviews` of a particular `movie` we would be having the URL like `movies/{movie_id}/actors/{actor_id}` or `movies/{movie_id}/reviews/{review_id}`. But since 'moves` `actors` `reviews` are itself actions, it's not working the way we intend... Not sure why, its so. Can anyone please look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71044199/struts2-wildcard-mapping-not-working-while-using-struts2-rest-api-implementation