# Personalized URL in Struts 2

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, url-rewriting, wildcard-mapping

I'm currently developing a Struts 2 web application that allow anonymous usage. I want that with anonymous user, the URL will be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

But after user logged in, the URL will be personalized base on user name, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/Cuong-Doan
```

Please suggest me a plugin/technique that can help me to achieve it.

Comment: May I know why do my question get down vote?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it with Tuckey's [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). After loging add session attribute, for example `loggedUsername=Cuong-Doan`. Then analyze this attribute in UrlRewriteFilter [rule](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#rule) using `session-attribute` parameter of [condition](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#condition) element. If it is present -> do redirect, add it to the URL using [backreferences](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#backreferences).

Comment: thank you for suggesting, I'll give it a try and feedback to you.

Answer (score 1):

Personalized could be done via setting the parameter specifying the persona. Looking at the URLs in the question I decided to give you imagination about technique used to reproduce SEO optimized URLs. This technique is called ["Parameters after action names"](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html). For example to map your persona with the action you can use

```
@Action(value = "/*", params = {"person", "{1}"})
```

so, after that action is mapped you will get the information about person via the `person` parameter that could be used in the action.

Comment: +1, @Doan this is the answer, no plugins needed. See my related answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855831/how-to-map-long-rest-urls-in-struts2-using-struts2-rest-plugin/15875522#15875522

Comment: @DoanCuong if you have multiple actions then you can use wildcards

Comment: @Roman C thank you for suggestion. May I ask one question? According to your answer, I suppose to put `{"person", "{1}"}` in every action to achieve `http://localhost:8080/myapp/Cuong-Doan/{action name}`, am I right?

@AndreaLigios Thank you for your suggest. Would you mind to put your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @DoanCuong you could use action name as a second parameter, and so on. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411736/passing-parameters-in-url-without-query-string-in-struts2/14415902#14415902

Comment: @DoanCuong One more comment using wildcards with named variable is not possible due to the pattern matchers are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @DoanCuong, just upvote RomanC answer... if you want to upvote my comment, simply upvote my other (linked) answer :)