# Creating dynamic URL with 2 action parameters in Struts 2 using OGNL

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2, ognl

If I have a url: `www.myurl.com/books` and want to be able to create new `<s:url>` filtering on author and year: `www.myurl.com/books/Sartre/1942` by passing `Sartre` and `1942` as parameters to the action class which will render the books page with the appropriate results. How to do this in Struts2?

I have the backend logic in place so it would be great if:

1. I could reuse the same jsp and action class that the permalink
   `www.myurl.com/books` uses.
2. Show the dynamically rendered URL `www.myurl.com/books/Sartre/1942`
   in the address bar even after the get request has loaded the page
   (not `www.myurl.com/books`, that is).

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/dynamic_URL.html

Comment: The page is only rendered if the parameters for author and year are found in the database.

Comment: Do you mean just that if parameters don't match the action doesn't return a result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `Advanced Wildcard Mappings`.

From the documentation: [Struts2's Advanced Wildcard Mappings](http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html):

> **Advanced Wildcards**
>
> From 2.1.9+ regular expressions can be defined defined in the action
>   name. To use this form of wild card, the following constants must be
>   set:
>
> ```xml
> <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/> 
> <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
> <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
> ```
>
> The regular expressions can be in two forms, the simplest one is
>   `{FIELD_NAME}`, in which case the field with the `FIELD_NAME` in the
>   action will be populated with the matched text, for example:
>
> ```xml
> <package name="books" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
>     <action name="/{type}/content/{title}" class="example.BookAction">
>         <result>/books/content.jsp</result>
>     </action> 
> </package>
> ```
>
> In this example, if the url `/fiction/content/Frankenstein` is
>   requested, BookAction's field "`type`" will be set to "`fiction`", and the
>   field "`title`" will be set to "`Frankenstein`".

If using Struts2-Convention-Plugin, your example would be:

```java
@Action(value="/books/{author}/{year}")
public class Books extends ActionSupport {
    private String  author; 
    private Integer year;
    /* ...GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE... */

    public String execute(){            
        /* ...LOAD DATA HERE... */
        if (noDataFound)
            return NONE;
        return SUCCESS
    }
}
```

If you need to work with those parameters in `prepare()` method, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19495332/1654265).

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with this type of configuration and tiles, only work with a class return but if it is call with other class proccess the execute method but return it's fail

Comment: This isn't working in `Struts 2.5.29`. Why so? Is there any work around for it?