# Struts2 regex configuration

Tags: java, regex, struts2, friendly-url, pretty-urls

I am creating a Struts2 web app.

I want an URL like `www.xyz.com/portal/orgCode/signin`, 
this orgCode is dynamic, so I am using regex for that.

I configure struts.xml like:

```xml
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",html,action" />
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*unfiltered.*,.*\\.nofilter" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2097152000"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/> 
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />

<package name="portal" namespace="/portal/{orgCode}" extends="default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="portalUrlInterceptor"
                    class="com.wtmit.service.portal.interceptor.PortalCommonInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="commonPortalUrlInterceptor">
            <interceptor-ref name="portalUrlInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <action name="signin" method="signin"
           class="com.wtmit.service.portal.action.PortalSignInAction">          
        <interceptor-ref name="commonPortalUrlInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="portalSignIn" type="tiles">portalSignIn</result>
        <result name="successLogin" type="redirect">home</result>

    </action>
</package>
```

this is working fine, but URLs like `www.xyz.com/mainLogin` is not working for the following configuration:

```xml
<package name="main" namespace="/" extends="default">
    <action name="*Login" method="{0}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="login" type="tiles">login</result>
        <result name="successLogin" type="redirect">home</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

The error is

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name mainLogin.

Comment: i think your question already has its answer... see the xml configuration once again...

Comment: Show your `default` package.

Comment: `<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
   <result-types><result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" /> <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
</result-types>
<global-results>
<result name="sessionExpire" type="redirect">./</result>
<result name="securityerror" type="tiles">error500</result>
</global-results>
<global-exception-mappings>
<exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="securityerror" />
</global-exception-mappings>
</package>`

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing [Wildcards](http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Wildcards) with [Advanced Wildcards](http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards); instead of this:

```xml
<action name="*Login" method="{0}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">
```

try using this:

```xml
<action name="/{method}/Login" method="{1}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">
```

Related reads:

- [Creating dynamic URL with 2 action parameters in Struts 2 using OGNL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097360/1654265)
- [Advanced Wildcard Mappings Parameters not found in Prepare() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19495332/1654265)

Comment: Thank you 
But in my case 

`<package name="portal" namespace="/portal/{orgCode}" extends="default">..`
and 
`<package name="main" namespace="/" extends="default">
    <action name="*Login" method="{0}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">
    </action>
</package>`
together is not working..
when i comment 
`<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />`
then 
`<package name="main" namespace="/" extends="default">
    <action name="*Login" method="{0}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">
    ..` is working fine and in that case regex mapping is not working

Comment: is this `<action name="/{method}/Login" method="{1}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">` working with [link](http://example.com/mainLogin)  http://example.com/mainLogin?

Comment: it is working with  `example.com/main/Login` . You could try with `<action name="/{method}Login" method="{1}" class="com.service.user.action.LoginAction">` otherwise

Comment: I can't change `<action name="*Login"`because this type is use in all application.
i am changing `<package name="portal" namespace="/portal" extends="default">   <action name="/{orgCode}/signin" method="{1}" class="com` for  (www.xyz.com/portal/abc/signin) but it is not working..


error is- "HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace /portal/abc  and action name signin."

www.xyz.com/portal/orgCode/signin