# Struts 2 with Rest Web service

Tags: web-services, rest, struts2

How to implement struts 2 with rest? 
How to configure web service **url patterns("/customerparticulars/getCustomerParticulars/{customercode}")** and **method types(GET,POST)** in **struts.xml** ?

Please share any sample application in any of the links!!

Comment: Are you sure you really need REST ? If you simply read RESTful URLs, just [go with advanced wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20097360/1654265). Otherwise, use Struts2-rest-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts 2 with REST- Not invoking struts.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670043/struts-2-with-rest-not-invoking-struts-xml)