# How to map URL contains slash in action (Wildcard mapping)

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, url-parameters, wildcard-mapping

I have a package name

```
/cabinet/s
```

where all actions return JSP snippets.

and the rest of the path of any URL for this package below

```
/cabinet/s/actionid/snippetgroup/filename.do
```

- actionid  - identifier for action class
- snippetgroup - identifier of snippets group for certain functionality (this is just a directory name)
- filename  -  JSP filename

```
<action name="actionid/*/*" class="someclass">
   <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}/{2}.jps</result>
</action>
```

The problem is that Struts never call a correct class. It always errors that `filename` action does not exist.

Struts application is configured to use `.do` extension instead of `.action`.

Comment: What about `.do`? Have you configured S2 to use it as action extension or not? If no then you need to remove it from the url.

Comment: @AleksandrM: add it to your answer... this cross-commenting is fuzzy ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Yep. :) Answering you previous question: The extension processing happens before parsing namespaces and such. So I doubt it will work with `.do` w/o appropriate config.

Comment: yes. i did override default .action extension to .do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set this options in struts.xml [according to the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html):

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

and *probably* remove the `.do` extension, by setting it to empty (or better to *comma*, to prevent Struts [handling static resources as namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629951/1654265)):

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
```

Otherwise, you can switch to [Advanced Wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875522/1654265) by using regex Pattern Matcher.

Comment: looks like struts has a lot of constants.

Comment: This are the only two Struts documentation tells you to alter to achieve the *Parameters after the action name* result :)

Comment: Please, try before keeping the .do extension, and come here to post the result, I'm curious to know if it works

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Probably not if it isn't configured so.

Answer (score 2):

In order this to work you need to set `struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames` to `true` and `struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace` to `false` in your configuration.

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

And you probably need to change your result to:

```
<result>/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}/{2}.jsp</result>
```

Also have you configured Struts2 to use `.do` as action extension or not? If no then you need to remove it from the url.

Comment: originally was absolute path not a relative. i fixed it in question.

Comment: @simar you should upvote this answer too since it says basically the same in mine and it was posted concurrently... Did it work with .do then?

Comment: How to use the same while working with Strtus2 REST api?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use relative path to the package specified. But you should use an absolute pathname.

```xml
<action name="actionid/*/*" class="someclass"> 
   <param name="snipetgroup">{1}</param>
   <param name="filename">{2}</param>
   <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/${snipetgroup}/${filename}.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

This technique is called [Parameters after the action name](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html#parameters-after-the-action-name). Note, this feature is available since Struts 2.2.1. Once applied you can use [dynamic parameters in result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html#dynamic-results).

Comment: originally was absolute path. i fixed it in question. i have seen named params techniques in struts docs but it was not important for me as line to enable SlashesInActionNames constant

Comment: @simar it doesn't help if you edit the question to fix your bugs from the answers of your question, next time you will end up solving your problems yourself.

Comment: @simar I might ignore if the line was not important to you, but have you followed that links, have you read the docs. You know that duplicate answers prohibited on SO, so why do you talk to me that line was important?

Comment: i solved question from first answer. Purpose of edit is for next man, who will be looking on this page. Since not a single person asked same specifying question i have decided to clear it in question itself, instead of adding comments to each answer.

Comment: i did read doc at first. i spend 2 hours reading in here http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html and experimenting with paths and configuration of struts.xml. Only after i gave up, i have asked question. I really i can't see how i could find out about constant needs to be activated from this page.

Comment: @simar If you followed my answer you'll see that URL has a fragment that directs you to the settings that I intentionally omitted here.

Comment: You are correct, i will pay more attention to Struts docs.