# Struts2 Wildcard mapping not working while using Struts2 REST api implementation

Tags: java, rest, url, struts2, wildcard-mapping

I am trying to implement the **SEO friendly URL** something like `/movies/{id}/actors/{actor_id}` to point out to the actor details of a particular movie. So I tried using the [Advanced Wildcard mappings](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html#advanced-wildcards), but it isn't working when I have the REST API implemention in my project, but the same is working in a project where I have a simple struts2 application, which shows the JSP pages as results.

Here are the files of the simple struts2 application that works:

`struts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
    <constant name="struts.matcher.appendNamedParameters" value="true"/>

    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="/{uid}/hello/{userName}" class="com.struts.kavin.action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
           <result name="success">/hello_world.jsp</result>
        </action> 
   </package> 
</struts>
```

`HelloWorldAction.java`

```
package com.struts.kavin.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorldAction  extends ActionSupport {
    private String userName;
    private String uid;

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

`hello_world.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Username: <s:property value="userName" /></p>
    <p>UID: <s:property value="uid" /></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

`index.jsp`: Displays the Hyperlinks to navigate to various pages.

**`OUTPUT:`**
`URL:` http://localhost:8080/Sample/dsadsadsad/hello/kavin.action

`Displays:`

> UID: dsadsadsad
>
> Username: kavin

---

Here are the files of the struts2 REST API application that doesn't work:

`struts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="action"/>

    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
    <constant name="struts.matcher.appendNamedParameters" value="true"/>

    <constant name="struts.rest.content.restrictToGET" value="false"/>

<package name="movies" extends="rest-default, json-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>

            <interceptor-stack name="jsonStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

<action name="movies" class="com.struts.movie.action.MoviesController">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"/>

            <result type="json">
                <!-- declarations for mappings from Request JSON Body goes here-->
                <param name="root">movie</param>
            </result>
        </action>

 </package>

 <package name="actors" namespace="/movies" extends="rest-default, json-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>

            <interceptor-stack name="jsonStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="/{movie_id}/actors/" class="com.struts.movie.action.ActorsController">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"/>
            <!-- <param name="movie_id">{1}</param> -->
            <result type="json">
                <!-- declarations for mappings from Request JSON Body goes here-->
                <param name="root">actor</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

`ActorsController.java`

```
package com.struts.movie.action;
public class ActorsController implements ModelDriven<Object> {
    private Actor actor;
    private String id;
    private String movie_id;
    private Object model;
    
    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    
   // RESETful method implementations

   // Respective getters & setters are added
}
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

`URL:` `GET:` http://localhost:8080/movie_api/movies/1/actors.json

`Error:`

> Struts Problem Report
>
> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> Messages:  There is no Action mapped for namespace /movies and action
> name 1. Stacktraces There is no Action mapped for namespace /movies
> and action name 1. - [unknown location]
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:195)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:76)
> org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(RestActionProxyFactory.java:50)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
> org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
> org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:648)
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
> org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
> org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

---

Can someone please help me to figure out what should be done to make it working? I also tried adding `<constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.Restful2ActionMapper" />` from [Restful2ActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/restful-action-mapper.html#restful2actionmapper).

Comment: The problem related to action mapper and action mapping for *non-mapped* URL could be resolved if you understand Struts configuration. To defeat configuration problems you'd better read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658006/573032) answer.

Comment: Thank you @RomanC, will check it out...